# ¿Cómo hacer que mi calculadora hecha en Javascript divida numeros?

Tags: javascript, operador

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var $btn0 = document.getElementById("btn0"),
        $btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1"),
        $btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2"),
        $btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3"),
        $btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4"),
        $btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5"),
        $btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6"),
        $btn7 = document.getElementById("btn7"),
        $btn8 = document.getElementById("btn8"),
        $btn9 = document.getElementById("btn9"),
        $btncolon = document.getElementById("btn,"),
        $btnplus = document.getElementById("btn+"),
        $btnminus = document.getElementById("btn-"),
        $btntimes = document.getElementById("btn*"),
        $btndivision = document.getElementById("btn/"),
        $btnresult = document.getElementById("btn="),
        $btnclr = document.getElementById("btnclr"),
        $btndel = document.getElementById("btndel");
    
    $btn0.addEventListener("click",function(){write(0)});
    $btn1.addEventListener("click",function(){write(1)});
    $btn2.addEventListener("click",function(){write(2)});
    $btn3.addEventListener("click",function(){write(3)});
    $btn4.addEventListener("click",function(){write(4)});
    $btn5.addEventListener("click",function(){write(5)});
    $btn6.addEventListener("click",function(){write(6)});
    $btn7.addEventListener("click",function(){write(7)});
    $btn8.addEventListener("click",function(){write(8)});
    $btn9.addEventListener("click",function(){write(9)});
    $btncolon.addEventListener("click",function(){write(".")});
    $btnplus.addEventListener("click",function(){operation("add")});
    $btnminus.addEventListener("click",function(){operation("sub")});
    $btntimes.addEventListener("click",function(){operation("mul")});
    $btndivision.addEventListener("click",function(){operation("div")});
    $btnresult.addEventListener("click",function(){result()});
    $btnclr.addEventListener("click",clear);
    $btndel.addEventListener("click",erase);
    
    var $cipher = "";
    var $display = $display = document.getElementById("display"),
        $number = [0,0],
        $counter = 0,
        $operations = ["",""],
        $btnresult2 = false;
    
    $display.style.textAlign = "right";
    
    function write(e){
        if($btnresult2 == true){ //clears all when you press a number btn to make a new operation.
            clear();
        }
        $cipher = $cipher + e;
        $display.value = $cipher;
    }
    
    function operation(op){
        $number[$counter] = parseFloat($cipher);
        $display.value="";
        $cipher = "";
        $operations[$counter] = op;
        $counter++;
        $btnresult2 = false; //prevents the calc. from displaying 0 after the result btn is pressed.
        if($counter == 2 && $operations[0] == "add"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] + $number[1];
            common();
        }else if($counter == 2 && $operations[0] == "sub"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] - $number[1];
            common();
        }else if($counter == 2 && $operations[0] == "mul"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] * $number[1];
            common();
        }else if($counter == 2 && $operations[0] == "div"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] / $number[1];
            common();
        }
    }
    
    function result(){
        if($operations[0] == "add"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] + parseFloat($display.value);
        }else if($operations[0] == "sub"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] - parseFloat($display.value);
        }else if($operations[0] == "mul"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] * parseFloat($display.value);
        }else if($operations == "div"){
            $number[0] = $number[0] / parseFloat($display.value);
        }
        $display.value = $number[0];
        $cipher = $number[0].toString(); //saves the result in case it wants to be used with another operation.
        $counter = 0;
        $btnresult2 = true;
    }
    
    function clear(){
        $cipher = "";
        $display.value = "";
        $number[0] = 0;
        $number[1] = 0;
        $operations[0] = "";
        $operations[1] = "";
        $counter = 0;
        $btnresult = false;
    }
    
    function erase(){
        $display.value = "";
        $cipher = "";
    }
    
    function common(){
        $operations[0] = $operations[1];
        $number[1] = 0;
        $counter = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 280px;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#display {
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.display {
    padding: 10px;
}
.keys {
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}
.firstrow, .secondrow, .thirdrow, .lastrow {
    display: inline-block;
}
.btnrow1, .btnrow2, .btnrow3 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}
.equal {
    display: inline-block;
}
.equal2 {
    width: 136px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
button:active {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="calculadora.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ejercicio%204%20styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="display">
            <input type="text" id="display" readonly="true">
        </div>
        <div class="keys">
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="firstrow"><button id="btn7" class="btnrow1">7</button></div>
                <div class="firstrow"><button id="btn8" class="btnrow1">8</button></div>
                <div class="firstrow"><button id="btn9" class="btnrow1">9</button></div>
                <div class="firstrow"><button id="btn+" class="btnrow1">+</button></div>
                <div class="firstrow"><button id="btn-" class="btnrow1">-</button></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="secondrow"><button id="btn4" class="btnrow2">4</button></div>
                <div class="secondrow"><button id="btn5" class="btnrow2">5</button></div>
                <div class="secondrow"><button id="btn6" class="btnrow2">6</button></div>
                <div class="secondrow"><button id="btn*" class="btnrow2">*</button></div>
                <div class="secondrow"><button id="btn/" class="btnrow2">/</button></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="thirdrow"><button id="btn1" class="btnrow3">1</button></div>
                <div class="thirdrow"><button id="btn2" class="btnrow3">2</button></div>
                <div class="thirdrow"><button id="btn3" class="btnrow3">3</button></div>
                <div class="thirdrow"><button id="btnclr" class="btnrow3">CLR</button>    </div>
                <div class="thirdrow"><button id="btndel" class="btnrow3">DEL</button>    </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="lastrow"><button id="btn0" class="btnrow3">0</button></div>
                <div class="lastrow"><button id="btn," class="btnrow3">.</button></div>
                <div class="equal"><button id="btn=" class="equal2">=</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi calculadora hecha desde cero por mi en JS por alguna razón no divide los números que le ingreso. Ya revise lo más evidente a mi parecer (que el signo de división esté presente, que las variables usadas estén bien escritas, que el botón de división tenga su correspondiente addeventlistener y que sus parametros están bien escritos...). también revisé la consola de mi navegador Chrome y no muestra ningún error (por si acaso).

Estudio por mi cuenta JS y trato de documentarme pero como soy nuevo en este mundo imagino que algo se me escapa. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? A lo mejor es una tontería pero yo no lo veo.

como extra podría mencionar que cada botón lo programé con addEventListener que, tengo entendido, es una forma más apropiada de programar un objeto más sin embargo veo que muchas personas llaman eventos con "onclick", "onblur", "onmouseover", etc. en etiquetas HTML entonces no se si la forma en que lo hice está bien o no.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, tienes un error en `}else if($operations == "div"){` debería ser `}else if($operations[0] == "div"){`, eso es todo. saludos.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias. Era una tontería realmente pero ya funciona perfecto.